# Android: Stop async task on button click

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am developing an application in which i am sending SMS in background on a button click. The code is as follows:

**On Click**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button_sendsms){
        onSendButtonClick();
    }
}
```

**Send SMS Method**

```
public void onSendButtonClick(){ 
    // Send SMS in background to the number entered by user for registration 
    sendSMSInBackground = new SendSMSInBackground();
    sendSMSInBackground.execute();  
}
```

**Background Class**

```
private class SendSMSInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    SeekBar seekBarMessageProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        seekBarMessageProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbaar_message_progress_susl_two);
        seekBarMessageProgress.setProgress(progress);
    }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    sendSMS("98********", "SMS");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    /*
     * My task
     */
    try{
        if(sentReceiver == null){}
        else{
            unregisterReceiver(sentReceiver);
        }
        if(deliverReceiver == null){}
        else{
            unregisterReceiver(deliverReceiver);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ** My Send SMS code**

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String randomNumber) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
        Intent deliveredUntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SignUpScreenActivity.this, 0,sentIntent, 0);        
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SignUpScreenActivity.this, 0,deliveredUntent, 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        sentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()){
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Utility.smsFlag = 2;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        deliverReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()){
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                      
                }
            }
        }; 

        try{
            registerReceiver(sentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
            registerReceiver(deliverReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, randomNumber, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

Now what the **need of the app** is:

I am having one more button on screen as stop button.
I want to stop the async task on click of that stop button and want to invoke new activity.

Please guide me what should i do now with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Are you sending a single SMS or more SMSes at a time?

Comment: Single SMS and only once from my app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending a single SMS or more SMSes at a time? I mean what is the actual scenario?

If you are sending a single SMS then you won't be able to stop/cancel this AsyncTask because as soon as you click, it will execute doInBackground() instantly.

If you are sending multiple SMS from `doInBackground()` then you can check `isCancelled()` inside the `doInBackground()` but it will true only when you call `asyncTask.cancel(true);` for your AsyncTask on button click.